# Regarding hadoop users and their respective permissions

Tags: linux, hadoop, ssh, permissions, mapreduce

Consider this scenario:
I have namenode user say **NN-USER-01**, this implies that **NN-USER-01** must be having passwordless ssh to all the datanodes present in the cluster so that all the communication between Namenode and Datanodes can be handled smoothly, right?

Now consider a case when I require to submit a job with different user from namenode say **NN-USER-02**, do I need to setup passwordless ssh between **NN-USER-02** and all the datanodes?
Are there any ways to handle this situation?

Answer (score 0):

No! All the user NN-User-02 needs is to have access to a new directory in the /user directory on the HDFS For eg.: /user/NN-USER-02. For the record, it is NOT mandatory for any user on any node to have passwordless SSH to all the nodes.Below is the reason for that:

The Namenode doesn't communicate with the Datanodes at all. Only the Datanodes communicate with the Namenode. So, by default you do not need any user to have a passwordless SSH to all the Datanodes. That said, we generally have passwordless SSh from one node (any 'one' user) to all the other nodes for easier distribution of configuration files (when changed in a tarball/package installation of the Hadoop Cluster) to all the nodes seamlessly without the hassle of entering the password everytime.